# php split and strcasecmp with user inputs comparison?

Tags: php, split, explode

I am simulating an address comparison that will determine the difference of a user's input to a google map api output. Let's say that $str1=is the user input and $str2=is the google output.

I use the ***split*** to break the strings into arrays and
strcasecmp to compare them. My question is how to compare all the array values that are split, currently it only compares 199a and 199 in this part.
***$var = strcasecmp($strarr[0], $strarr2[0]);***

***Update...........***

```
<?php
$str1 = "199a Freestone Road, Sladevale QLD 4370, Australia";
$str2 = "199 Freestone Road, Sladevale QLD 4370, Australia";

$strarr = (explode(" ",$str1));
echo("<br>");

$strarr2 = (explode(" ",$str2));
echo("<br>");

$var = strcasecmp($strarr[0], $strarr2[0]);
echo"$var";

if($var===0)
{
    echo("The Strings are equal.");
}

elseif ($var==!0) 
{
    echo("<br>");
    echo("wafasd");  
}
```

I appreciate all your suggestions on just directly compare the two arrays,yes it may solve the  current comparison problem, but due to some parts of the current project I am working on I am not sure if it is suited. I'll elaborate it below

User's Input: 199a Sladevale Road, Sladevale QLD 4370, Australia
Google Map API Output: 199 Freestone Road, Sladevale QLD 4370, Australia

Changes(this is what I am trying to achieve):
199a is changed by Google into 199
Sladevale is changed by Google into Freestone

Comment: Replace `split` with `explode` as split() is deprecated as of **5.3.0**

Comment: if the value of var is not equal to zero, it should echo the strings that are different, in this case 199a and 199, but to save the trouble, if var is not equal to zero output wasfasd.

Comment: just compare the two arrays -> `if ($strarr==$strarr2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both arrays are at the same length then you can just loop through them:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($strarr);$i++) {
    $var = strcasecmp($strarr[$i], $strarr2[$i]);
    echo $var."<br>";
}
```

And use `explode()` instead of `split()`. `split()` is deprecated and should not be used, because it could be removed in the next version of PHP. `explode()` does exactly the same.

Comment: yes in this example the 2 arrays are of the same length but as I said I am simulating on how to compare a user's input and google map api output, which is a situation where you cannot determine the length of a user's input, may I ask if  the array are not of the same length would it still work? thnx I appreciate your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `if ($strarr==$strarr2)` to compare to arrays.
Another way is to use array_diff in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str1 = "199 Freestone Road, Sladevale QLD 4370, Australia";
    $str2 = "199a Freestone Road, Sladevale QLD 4370, Australia";

    $strarr = (explode(" ",$str1));
    echo("<br>");

    $strarr2 = (explode(" ",$str2));
    echo("<br>");

    if ($strarr == $strarr2) {echo "equal array";} else {echo "not equal array";}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works..

```
<?php
$str1 = "199a Freestone Road, Sladevale QLD 4370, Australia";
$str2 = "199 Freestone Road, Sladevale QLD 4370, Australia";

$strarr1 = split(" ",$str1);
echo("<br>");

$strarr2 = split(" ",$str2);
echo("<br>");
$count = count($strarr1);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$flag = 0;
$var = strcasecmp($strarr1[$i], $strarr2[$i]);
if($var===0)
{
    $flag =0;//match
}

elseif ($var==!0) 
{
    $flag = 1;//mismatch
    echo "strings not match!";
    exit;
}
}
if($flag ==0)
echo "strings match!";

?>
```